# Would there have been the same risk with Gnome 3.16 if it had been included in Ubuntu Gnome 15.04?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

I am currently running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, with Gnome 3.14, and I am contemplating upgrading to Gnome 3.16, in the article [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/06/how-to-upgrade-to-gnome-3-16-in-ubuntu-15-04) I read that:

> The stable release of GNOME 3.16 arrived in March.
>
> It comes with a bunch of neat app updates, a new look ‘shell’ and a
>   slick new notification center. All great stuff, but all arriving too
>   late in the Ubuntu development cycle to be included by default in
>   Ubuntu 15.04.
>
> Since GNOME is an intrinsic part of the regular Unity desktop used by
>   millions around the around the decision was made to stick with the
>   older, but thoroughly tested, GNOME 3.14 release.
>
> You can, should want to you, upgrade GNOME 3.14 to 3.16 in Ubuntu —
>   but it’s not recommended.
>
> Upgrading GNOME involves more than a few apps and icon themes. You are
>   swapping out older, well tested components of your operating system
>   for newer, largely untested replacements.
>
> If you’re entomophobic (a fancy word for being scared of bugs) or hate
>   software headaches (no fancy word for that) this tutorial is not for
>   you.
>
> To repeat: you can upgrade to GNOME 3.16 in Ubuntu 15.04 but it is not
>   recommended and may not give stable, reliable experience at the end.

So they are basically telling me that I shouldn't upgrade if I don't want major problems. Would they have said the same thing even if 3.16 had been released at a time when it could have been put as the default for Ubuntu 15.04? Would they then be saying that you shouldn't upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 if you don't want big problems with Gnome?

So basically what I am getting at is are there any problems that would occur if I upgraded to Gnome 3.16, that would not have been present if Ubuntu 15.04 had included Gnome 3.16 as default?

**Note:** Please don't close this as primarily opinion-based, because I am not looking for opinions, I am looking for facts. I just want to know if there is any more danger in upgrading to it, than there would be if it was just included as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion based answer is, I have fewer problems with GNOME 3.16 as with GNOME 3.14 in my GNOME Ubuntu 15.04 with proprietary nvidia drivers.

A warning for not supported software is always good to avoid discussions.

GNOME 3.16 is released since weeks and the PPAs have some patches included. That's a good sign for me.

Ok, maybe there are some apps which not work properly, eg. GNOME Music. But that's not a real problem.

I would never get back GNOME 3.14.

Comment: But would they have said the same about Gnome 3.16 if it had been included with Ubuntu 15.04 as the default?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe, it's a political statement.

Comment: And if they had included 3.16 in Ubuntu 15.04 as default, would the same issues be present as those that could arise if I upgrade to 3.16? Basically what I am getting at is, is there any difference between it being included as default, and me upgrading to it? Is one more dangerous than the other? Or does it not make a difference?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no difference.